# Verify Certificate After Response

Tags: go

I want to connect to potentially insecure hosts, so I'm using `http.Client` like so:

```
client := &http.Client{
    Timeout: timeout,
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    },
}
resp, err := client.Get(url)
```

Which works well and fine, but I can't seem to find a way to check the validity of an SSL certificate after the fact. I realize I can make two connections (one with `InsecureSkipVerify` and one without), but I'd like to do this without making another connection.

Comment: Why exactly not another connection?

Comment: I'll be running this against a large number of endpoints, so I'd like to conserve resources where I can.

Comment: It is not as if you are holding two connections. You connect once, discard the connection and connect again with different flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doable. =)

You should set Dial and DialTLS fields on Transport and do checks there.

Hope the code is self explanatory, feel free to ask.

Does not work on playground due to restrictions!

https://play.golang.org/p/4TkczUEnKn

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net"
    "time"
    "crypto/tls"
)

func DialTLS(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := tls.Dial(network, addr, &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    })

    cs := conn.ConnectionState()
    fmt.Println(cs.Version, cs.HandshakeComplete)
    // insert your check here!

    return conn, err
}

func Dial (network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {    
    // Copied from DefaultTransport
    dialer := &net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        }
    conn, err := dialer.Dial(network, addr)

    fmt.Println("unsecure")

    return conn, err
}

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial: Dial,

        // If DialTLS is set, the Dial hook is not used for HTTPS
        // requests and the TLSClientConfig and TLSHandshakeTimeout
        // are ignored. The returned net.Conn is assumed to already be
        // past the TLS handshake.

        // TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        //  InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        // },           
            DialTLS: DialTLS,
        },
    }

    // Deep in transport it checks "tlsDial := t.DialTLS != nil && cm.targetScheme == "https" && cm.proxyURL == nil"
    // https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#L741
    resp, err := client.Get("https://www.google.com")
    fmt.Println(resp, err, "\n\n")

    resp , err = client.Get("http://www.google.com")
    fmt.Println(resp, err)
}
```

**UPD**

*UPD2*: Code below is bad idea =). Fallback logic confuses http.Client `error = Get https://www.google.com: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client` or I am missing something, well, its up to you now =)

Or even better (depends on your logic).

```
func DialTLSWithFallback(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := tls.Dial(network, addr, &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    })

    if err != nil {
        // obviously, usecure
        // lets try net.Dial
        // and return, so check bellow wont trigger on wrong connection type
        return &(net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
        }).Dial(network, addr)
    }

    cs := conn.ConnectionState()
    fmt.Println(cs.Version, cs.HandshakeComplete)
    // its "secure" connection
    // check is it strong enough here!

    return conn, err
}
```

And you transport shrinks to

```
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial: DialTLSWithFallback,          
            DialTLS: DialTLSWithFallback,
        }
```